# many to many relationship with three tables (sql-alchemy)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a many to many relationship working. I have three tables

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

class Groups(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))

class Members(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'))
```

I would like to have the option group.members, which should give me all User objects which are member of that group. I implemented it the following way

```
members = db.relationship('User', secondary="join(Members, User, Members.user_id == User.id)", primaryjoin="and_(Groups.id == Members.group_id)")
```

this seems to work, but when I delete a group it gives me (sometimes) the error

AttributeError: 'Join' object has no attribute 'delete'

so I guess this is not the right way to implement such a relation. 
Any ideas how to do this correctly?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler way to implement this is as follows (adapted from the [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/#many-to-many-relationships) on Flask-SQLAlchemy

```
members = db.Table('members',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'))
)

class Groups(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    members = db.relationship('User', secondary=members, backref=db.backref('group', lazy='dynamic'))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
```

Instead of using a Model for the joining table (members), let's just use a simple table.

With this configuation, you can easily add/remove members and groups:

```
u = User(username='matt')
g = Groups(name='test')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.add(g)
db.session.commit()
g.members.append(u)
db.session.commit()
db.session.delete(g)
db.session.commit()
```